# Run command for every line of a file in bash, passing lines as standard input

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, redirection, stdin

How do I pass some input to a command line by line (ie. invoke the command for every line)?

`xargs` does not work because it passes the lines as arguments, not as standard input.

The specific case where this came up was decoding a file whose lines were base64-encoded strings.

Answer (score 9):

Can be done with a while loop:

```
produce | while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line" | process; done | consume
```

(for some arbitrary `produce`, `process`, `consume` commands which all use standard input/output) but meh. There has to be a more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: (Semicolon is after `line`, not after `do`)